# Necessary permissions to use externtal program from Java

Tags: java, linux, permissions, external

Java application that I wrote depends on small C program. I decided to place executable version of that program in resources and when user start my app, app will create temp version of that program, and delete the same when it is closed.

Here is constructor of main java program :

```
public RankingCreator(String title) {
    super(title);

    if (!tempJudgeCreated) { // static variable
        try {
            InputStream istream = (InputStream) getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/IOIJudge");
            byte[] tempJudgeBytes = new byte[SIZE_OF_JUDGE];
            istream.read(tempJudgeBytes);
            istream.close();
            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(JUDGE);
            ostream.write(tempJudgeBytes);
            ostream.flush();
            ostream.close();
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 " + JUDGE); // this line creates confusion
            tempJudgeCreated = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This work perfectly while I am in Eclipse, but when I export this in runnable JAR, this code fails, and does not even proceed to GUI part. When I remove Runtime.getRuntime()... it proceeds to GUI, but I do not have necessary permissions to use it (temp program).